# Why webpage size is diffrent from saved (on disk) size?

Tags: firefox, html

For example I opened Google.com in firefox and go to page info General, it says "size is 62.99 KB (64,498 bytes)" after I save webpage on disk the html page size is 208.9 kB (208,877 bytes) and the total size (html+images) is 941.3 kB.

**Firefox Size:**
[image]

**Size on Disk:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webservers can use *[gzip compression](https://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html)* to compress text files as HTML and CSS. Using that trick the files are transfered faster.

Your first image is the size of the compressed file.

When the browser has downloaded the file then it decompressses it. That is the size you see on your second image.

In this case the transferred file size is 30% of the original one.

Comment: You can see the difference if you go to the network tab in Developer Tools and check the columns "Transferred" and "Size" for file "/", after reloading the page.